# "В соответствии" и "на основании" синонимы или нет?

Tags: семантика

Пример: "в соответствии со стандартом" или "на основании стандарта". Насколько я знаю, в юриспруденции они имеют различный смысл, скажите, так ли это?

Answer (score 3):

"В соответствии со стандартом" и "на основании стандарта" не являются синонимами.

Из словаря:
**На основании** чего в зн. предлога. **Исходя из чего-л., опираясь на что-л**. Действовать на основании закона. **<В соответствии** с чем в зн. предлога. В соответствии с планом, с графиком.

**Пример**

(1) Программа дошкольного образования разработана **на  основании**  Федерального государственного образовательного стандарта. (2) **В соответствии** с ФГОС   программа должна обеспечивать  развитие личности и способностей детей в различных видах деятельности.

Таким образом, в одном случае **указывается** регулирующий определенную деятельность **стандарт**, а в другом - **контролируется** должное **исполнение стандарта** в процессе этой деятельности.

Answer (score 2):

Употребление зависит от контекста. **На основании** стандарта заинтересованные лица или организации предъявляют к изделию технические требования, а разрабатывается и изготавливается изделие **в соответствии** с этим стандартом (соответствует стандарту по оговоренным в нём техническим характеристикам).

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае скорее всего можно считать синонимами. Но хотелось бы контекст, подробнее - см. ниже.

Про юриспруденцию вообще - не знаю, хотелось бы конкретный пример, демонстрирующий разницу в значениях.

Что касается бытового употребления, то тут можно заметить, что "в соответствии" в целом шире по значению, чем "на основании" Последнее означает только какое-то действие и некое положение (обычно правоустанавливающее), дающее разрешении и обязывающее такое действие выполнить. ***На основании анализа ДНК экспертиза установила, что гр. Разэтакий Такой Сякоевич является генетическим отцом ребенка.*** Тут можно и "в соответствии", но не так обязывающе.

А вот ***"Дом на участке гр. Немазанного построен в соответствии с законом"*** и ***"... на основании ..."*** - это уже две разные формулировки. *"В соответствии с законом"* означает, что все положения закона соблюдены, а "на основании" - скорее то, что закон дал разрешение, но при этом не очевидно, что *Немазанный гр.* соблюл все необходимые положения такого закона. Так что разница тут есть, хотя довольно тонкая..

Если, говоря про юриспруденцию, вы имели ввиду нечто подобное, то да, это разные понятия. Ну и в отношении стандарта тоже такое понимание не исключается, хотя по мне - маловероятно. Напишите всю фразу полностью - разберемся.